# How to use OAuth in Coldfusion application?

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, google-docs-api

I want to authorize my web-application for all users landing on it with a common google account. I am using google Document List API and want other users to get authorized by the common google account whenever they want to access the document.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please use search first? You CONSTANTLY asking questions that are duplicates. You DEFINITELY can see them in Related list at the sidebar and at the new question form.

Answer (score 3):

OAuth only connects your application to the target authenticator (Google).  You would still need your application to proxy for the end user, your application cannot create a direct connection between Google and the end-user.

That said, http://oauth.riaforge.org/index.cfm is pretty easy to use.  I used it to connect to a third party application from mine and, once I figured out the basics of OAuth, it was pretty easy.  I then wrote a wrapper for all the internal functions to ease integration.

So, the OAuth package at RIAForge will make it pretty easy to authenticate your application to Google, but will not create a direct line between Google and your end-user.